# Symlinks dont work after restarts-- then restarting nautilus fixes it

Tags: dual-boot, nautilus, macosx, symbolic-link

I'm having some problems with soft links that direct to folders in a partition I'm using to share files between Ubuntu and OSX. When I first set everything up it all worked perfectly, but after a restart the links come up as broken.

I can get everything to work correctly again by killing Nautilus and reopening. After that everything shows up completely normal until my next restart.

What is the best way to go about fixing it so that it shows up correctly without having to go into the terminal every time I turn on the machine? Is there some step that I missed setting this all up?

Comment: Do the symlinks work when following them via a terminal? I.e. does `ls /somedir/symlink` give the contents of `/someotherdir/linkedfile`. Check so immediately after boot and a few moments later, once without and once with restarting the file manager. [Edit] your question, adding the results.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question and tell us i) what filesystem you're using and ii) whether the links are on the same filesystem.

Comment: It sounds like the files are on a partition which isn't mounted (at least until Nautilus or something else tries to access them). If that's the problem, then there are different solutions depending on when the partition "should" be mounted. If it's all the time, then you can add an entry to /etc/fstab to automount it. If it's sometimes, you can write a script to mount it. Then, you just have to figure out a mechanism to run that script when appropriate to your situation.